# How do I add and retrieve structured data from an elasticsearch in-memory node?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I am experimenting with the elasticsearch (1.4) API in a Scala project.
My most trivial goal is to add data to an in memory node and retrieve it afterwards. I am widely following the examples given in the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices.html). Still, I experience odd behaviour.

```scala
def clusterName: String = "foo-bar"
def indexName: String = "lorem"
def typeName: String = "ipsum"

// ES Settings
var elasticsearchSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("index.gateway.type", "none")
    .put("index.number_of_shards", 1)
    .put("index.number_of_replicas", 0)
    .put("path.data", "target/es-data")
    .put("index.store.type", "memory").build()

// ES Node
var node = nodeBuilder()
    .clusterName(clusterName)
    .local(true)
    .settings(elasticsearchSettings).node()

// ES Client
var client = node.client()

// Preapring ES Index
var preparation = client.prepareIndex(indexName, typeName)
    .setSource(s"""{"foo" : "bar"}""")
    .execute()
    .actionGet()

// Preparing Request
val requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
    .setFrom(0)
    .setSize(20)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(null, null))

val response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet(5000)
```

My expectation is that this response now has the length of 1 (containing the resource `foo`).

Running `println(response)`, however generates the following output:

```
{
  "took" : 32,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Why is my newly added resource not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I managed to solve this problem by refreshing the shards after preparing the index.

This is done by calling `client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().execute().actionGet()` after `client.prepareIndex`.

Consider the following working example:

```scala
def clusterName: String = "foo-bar"
def indexName: String = "lorem"
def typeName: String = "ipsum"

// ES Settings
var elasticsearchSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("index.gateway.type", "none")
    .put("index.number_of_shards", 1)
    .put("index.number_of_replicas", 0)
    .put("path.data", "target/es-data")
    .put("index.store.type", "memory").build()

// ES Node
var node = nodeBuilder()
    .clusterName(clusterName)
    .local(true)
    .settings(elasticsearchSettings).node()

// ES Client
var client = node.client()

// Preapring ES Index
var preparation = client.prepareIndex(indexName, typeName)
    .setSource(s"""{"foo" : "bar"}""")
    .execute()
    .actionGet()

// Important: Refresh the index 
client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh(indexName).execute().actionGet()

// Preparing Request
val requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
    .setFrom(0)
    .setSize(20)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(null, null))

val response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet(5000)
```

The resource `{foo : "bar"}` is then returned as expected.